# CodeIgniter doesn't allow '0' as a valid URL parameter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Why doesn't CI allow the number zero as a valid URL parameter?!
To rule out some mistake in my code, I have a clean install of PyroCMS, and just display the seconde URL parameter. 
Everything works except when is `www.mysite.com/page/0`
Thought it was a PyroCMS problem, but CI alone has the same behaviour.
Thanks.

Comment: It is allowed, you may have an issue elsewhere causing a problem.

Comment: There's more people with the same problem.

Comment: I just tested it and works fine in my CI site - see my answer below.

Comment: Its not a codeigniter Problem, 0 Works. xD

Comment: Hmmmm... PyroCMS problem then. I'll check again, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed.

I just tested it on my Codeigniter site. You likely have an issue elsewhere causing a problem.

You're going to have to account for the second URL parameter in your `routes.php` file, see [CodeIgniter Routing Docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

0 will also be sent to the relevant controller as a parameter, so if your controller is set up like this:

```
function pages ($var){
    //controller stuff
}
```

0 will be passed to the function as `$var` and if your logic is set up so that 0 causes a problem, then that is your issue.

Comment: I'll test it again. thnx

Answer (score 1):

in your CI application folder check the file: config/config.php

around line 118 look for: Allowed URL Characters

by default 0 - 9 are allowed but maybe Pyro changes this.

Comment: Checked. Has the default value.